# Issue with Manage Content and Structure

Tags: wcm

I have an issue with the "Manage Content and Structure" feature of my SharePoint 2010 site. In my site collection root I have 2 sub sites. Both are publishing sites with custom branding applied. Both sites are almost identical with only difference in list content type fields. The source site "Site 1" contains "Pages" library with "col1" as the additional column in the "Article Page" content type. In the second site "Site 2" same content type has "col2" as additional column.

My expection is when I copy a page from "Site1" pages library to "Site2" pages library, I will get both "col1" as well as "col2" in the "Site2" (destination) library. But what happens is very strange. Content copy works perfectly without any error but when I check the destination library, I can see the "col2" that was added to its "Article Page" content type is removed. But it's there for other content types (page, welcome page) (I added "col2" to all content types of the "pages" library)

Spent a lot of time but with no luck.

Can anyone please help?

Posted same question in [MSDN forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/adacb0c8-4100-4a7a-bd42-d19bab65b24c/issue-with-manage-content-and-structure) as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it might be related to multiple aspects, such as which Content type is the default per each Pages library, to which of your library-scoped content types you added the columns, the actual page layout to which content type is associated, etc.

I would suggest you follow:

1. Create your own Content Types at the Site Collection level - inherit
   from existing ones to ensure the proper usage of the Page Layouts.
2. Add these to your Pages Library in both source and target sites
3. Make the copy.

Comment: Perfect!...Worked like a charm. Thank you so much Marius. Here is what I did. I created a a new content type "Inherited Article page" based on "Article page" and then added "Col2" as a site column to it. Then I associated that content type to my "Site 2" library as the default content type. After all these setup I coptied a file from "Site 1" library to "Site 2" library and I can see both "Col1" (from source) as well as "Col2" in the properties window. Eventhough I don't understand what is the root cause, I am happy that it saved my life. Thanks again Marius.

Comment: Happy I could help!